# deleting web content programmatically in liferay 6.0

Tags: liferay, webcontent

I am new to liferay. I am developing delete scheduler, which has to delete documents programatically based on some condition. using `DLfileLocalServiceUtil.deleteFileEntry(id)` I can delete it, but it is deleting only entry in `DlfileEntry` table not the actual file stored in file system in server in data folder.

Answer (score 0):

DLfileLocalServiceUtil is used for managing Documents. You need to use 'JournalArticle*Util' APIs to deal with Web Contents. There are multiple Util classes for different purpose. You'll perhaps need JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.deleteJournalArticle() methods for deleting the web contents.

Comment: **But pay attention!** Calling `*LocalServiceUtil` delete method is the wrong way to delete an asset. You have to use XXXServiceUtil!

Comment: Yes, it is better to use ServiceUtil vs LocalServiceUtil for security reasons (and may be more).